# XSL: removing preceding folders on image path

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to remove preceding './' and first folder if it is not named 'screenshots'

So from

```
<image href="./folderx/screenshots/page1.png">
<image href="./screenshots/page2.png"/>
<image href="./views/screenshots/table/screenshots/page3.png"/>
```

to

```
<image href="screenshots/page1.png">
<image href="screenshots/page2.png"/>
<image href="screenshots/table/screenshots/page3.png"/>
```

---

The Solution below does this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE reference
  PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Composite//EN" "http://docs.oasis-open.org/dita/v1.1/OS/dtd/reference.dtd">
<reference id="sample">
   <title>Sample Title</title>
   <refbody>
      <section>
         <title>Breadcrumb</title>
         <p>
            <xref href=""/>  
            <xref href=""/>
            <xref href=""/>
         </p>
      </section>
      <section>
         <title>Screenshot</title>
         <p id="Typ1e">
            <image href="./views/screenshots/Type1.png" placement="break"/>
         </p>
         <p id="Type2">
            <image href="./views/screenshots/Type2.png" placement="break"/>
         </p>
      </section>
   </refbody>
</reference>
```

To:

```
<reference xmlns:ditaarch="http://dita.oasis-open.org/architecture/2005/" id="sample"
           ditaarch:DITAArchVersion="1.2"
           domains="(topic concept)                            (topic concept glossentry)                            (topic concept glossgroup)                            (topic reference)                            (topic task)                            (topic hi-d)                             (topic ut-d)                             (topic indexing-d)                            (topic hazard-d)                            (topic abbrev-d)                            (topic pr-d)                             (topic sw-d)                            (topic ui-d)                             (topic task strictTaskbody-c)    "
           class="- topic/topic       reference/reference ">
   <title class="- topic/title ">Sample Title</title>
   <refbody class="- topic/body        reference/refbody ">
      <section class="- topic/section ">
         <title class="- topic/title ">Breadcrumb</title>
         <p class="- topic/p ">
            <xref href="" class="- topic/xref "/>  
            <xref href="" class="- topic/xref "/>
            <xref href="" class="- topic/xref "/>
         </p>
      </section>
      <section class="- topic/section ">
         <title class="- topic/title ">Screenshot</title>
         <p id="Typ1e" class="- topic/p ">
            <image href="screenshots/Type1.png" placement="break" class="- topic/image "/>
         </p>
         <p id="Type2" class="- topic/p ">
            <image href="screenshots/Type2.png" placement="break" class="- topic/image "/>
         </p>
      </section>
   </refbody>
</reference>
```

Using XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match=
        "image/@href[starts-with(.,'./')
        and not(starts-with(.,'./screenshots/'))
        ]">
        <xsl:attribute name="href">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-after(.,'./'), '/')"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="image/@href[starts-with(.,'./screenshots/')]">
        <xsl:attribute name="href">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(.,'./')"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm not sure if this is relevant, but I'm using oXygen 12.0

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a "standards-based" solution that does exactly what this question asks for. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: The OP (@Ace) has modified his question and reports that the transformation below produces some new, additional attributes.

This effect is due to the fact that he is using `<!DOCTYPE` and the associated DTD gives some default attributes to some of the elements.

So, nothing new or surprizing! :)

This will always happen when you have a `<!DOCTYPE` instruction that associates a DTD to the document and when this DTD has default attributes.

To remove the attributes, in case they are not wanted, one can add matching tempate(s) with empty body. **However, be aware that this may render the whole result invalid for the DTD**!

---

**This is a mechanical override of the identity rule:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
   "image/@href[starts-with(.,'./')
              and not(starts-with(.,'./screenshots/'))
                ]">
  <xsl:attribute name="href">
   <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-after(.,'./'), '/')"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="image/@href[starts-with(.,'./screenshots/')]">
  <xsl:attribute name="href">
   <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(.,'./')"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<t>
    <image href="./folderx/screenshots/page1.png"/>
    <image href="./screenshots/page2.png"/>
    <image href="./views/screenshots/table/screenshots/page3.png"/>
</t>
```

**the wanted result is produced**:

```
<t>
    <image href="screenshots/page1.png"></image>
    <image href="screenshots/page2.png"></image>
    <image href="screenshots/table/screenshots/page3.png"></image>
</t>
```

Comment: Yes Perfect!  The parsing works exactly the way i want it to.  Just of out curiosity, when I run this on my .dita file, i get class="- topic/p "> added to all my <p> tags, and I have similar additions to all my other tags.  Is there an option i should be setting?

Comment: @Ace: It isn't possible that this transformation adds a new attribute -- I'd be interested to see your XML document.

Comment: @Dimitre:  I agree your .xsl does not have anything to suggest that it would do that.  I've posted whats happening as an edit to my answer.

Comment: @Dimitre:  My Answer has been edited to show the xml before and after I apply your transformation.

Comment: @Ace: just the XML is not sufficient. Please, provide the minimal transformation (XSLT stylesheet) that produces the reported results from the provided XML document.

Comment: @Dimitre: The XSLT is identical to the one you have supplied.  I've added to my question.

Comment: @Ace: This is due to the `<!DOCTYPE` instruction. Obviously, the DTD contains some default attributes. If you don't want these, simply remove the `<!DOCTYPE` instruction. I have verified that with it removed, you don't get the additional attributes.

Comment: @Ace: I added an Update to my answer, explaining your problem.